# django-table2 multi-column sorting UI

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am trying to do multi-column sorting in django-tables2.

I can add `?sort=date&sort=job_number`
to the end of my url and it will sort by date, then job number.

But when a user clicks a column heading, it will replace the current sort querystring with the new one!  Is there a way to more elegantly expose multi-column sort to the end users?

I am using the 'querystring' tag from django-tables2, but as stated above, it rewrites the value instead of appending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I have worked out a solution that works, but it isn't quite perfect, so if anyone wants to propose something better, I'm all ears!

First, I created a new templatetag (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/ for details about where to put a custom templatetag)

```
from django import template

from django_tables2.templatetags.django_tables2 import querystring

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('django_tables2/header.html', takes_context=True)
def render_header(context):
    for column in context['table'].columns:
        column.sort_existing = False
        if 'sort' in context['request'].GET:
            if column.name in context['request'].GET['sort']:
                column.sort_existing = True

    return context
```

Then, I created a custom template called django_tables2/header.html for that tag to use:

```
{% load querystring from django_tables2 %}

<thead>
<tr>
    {% for column in table.columns %}
        {% if column.orderable %}
          {% if column.sort_existing %}
            <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}><a href='{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}'>{{ column.header }}</a></th>
          {% else %}
            <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}><a href='{% querystring %}&{{ table.prefixed_order_by_field }}={{ column.order_by_alias }}'>{{ column.header }}</a></th>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <th {{ column.attrs.th.as_html }}>{{ column.header }}</th>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
</thead>
```

And Finally, I altered my django_tables2/table.html template to use my custom templatetag to render the table header, replace the table.thead block with:

```
    {% block table.thead %}
        {% render_header %}
    {% endblock table.thead %}
```

And that should do the trick!  Clicking on multiple column headers will sort them in the order clicked, clicking on a the same one twice will clear previous selections (and reverse the order).  It isn't perfect.  Perhaps I'll improve upon it later, but it works for my immediate use case.

Perhaps I will reach out to the django_tables2 project to see if they are interested in including my custom template tag into the main project :)

EDIT: I should note, this requires 'django.core.context_processors.request' or equivalent in your context processors in your settings.

EDIT: Fixed table.html to correct code.  Also, see https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/223 to track this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not an option for django-tables2 at the moment, though it is noted as an [issue on the git page](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/issues/223). I would also like to see this as on option for this package as well.

Looking through the source code briefly in the table.html template the `href` for the column header is produced by the following code: `{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}`. Digging a little deeper it appears that there is an `OrderByTuple` object, that seems to want to perform this function, but never gets passed to the rendering. I haven't dug down enough to figure out why this `OrderByTuple` is not passed to the href, but may have something to do with the fact the the OrderBy called from the template referenced above is linked to the column and not the table. Sorry I couldn't acutually come up with a solution, but hope this helps a little.